# Where are categories and products stored in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress.

I am studying an already made site which has WooCommerce plugin.

Well, please see this image which shows a product list:

[image]

I have spent some hours trying to find where products and categoríes are stored. There is not a `product` table neither `category` table neither a database table with similar names.

I have also exported the whole database in SQL format and then trying to find the product name or category name, but I could not find them.

Any one can point me to the right direction?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce products are stored in wp_posts table with post_type column value as "product" and "product_variation".

Any additional product data will be stored in the wp_postmeta table.

The product categories and tags both are stored in the wp_terms table and can be identified as a category or tag based on its data in the wp_term_taxonomy table where it stores the product_cat value in the "taxonomy" column.